# Installing tt-rss : files arn't where they ought to be

Tags: installation, 12.10, tt-rss

I'm currently trying to install the tt-rss package (Tiny Tiny RSS) on Ubuntu 12.10 via Ubuntu's official packages.

The installation process *seems* to have worked - but the files I need to run are on `/usr/share/tt-rss` rather than `/var/www/something`.

Its obviously not working for me - the databases *seem* to be set up; the install process went through once I worked out I needed mysql client and server, but the web server isn't picking up the tt-rss install.

What else do I need to do to get tt-rss working?

Comment: Another Google Reader soon-to-be orphan. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu packages are not supposed to install anything in `/var/www`. Instead, the recommended approach is to install your application into `/usr/share`. This is what tt-rss has done as well. The site is located at:

```
/usr/share/tt-rss/www
```

The package installer creates a default Apache HTTP configuration file at `/etc/tt-rss/apache.conf`. To enable it, we'll just link it into `/etc/apache2/conf.d`:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/tt-rss/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/tt-rss
sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 reload
```

You should now be able to surf to `http://localhost/tt-rss`, where you will be greeted by an error message:

[image]

To fix this, simply edit `/etc/tt-rss/config.php` and adjust the `SELF_URL_PATH` according to your setup. Afterwards, refresh the page to see the login screen.

[image]

You'll still have to properly configure tt-rss. But this should get you started.

After working on it a bit more, it is apparent that the packaged version is not compatible with the default prototype 1.7.0 that is installed by default. To remedy this, install an older version of prototype locally:

```
cd /usr/share/tt-rss/lib 
sudo rm prototype.js
sudo wget http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js
```

Now it should let you log in with the default `admin`/`password` login.

[image]